# How to correctly use a Delegate function with IConfigueOptions in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In the .Net Core documentation they point this example to use a delegate function:

```
// Example #2: Options bound and configured by a delegate
services.Configure<MyOptionsWithDelegateConfig>(myOptions =>
{
    myOptions.Option1 = "value1_configured_by_delegate";
    myOptions.Option2 = 500;
});
```

I can get that to work, but I want to call a method to fully flesh out the Options object like this:

```
    private void RegisterOptionsFromDatabase(OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory, IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // Example #2: Options bound and configured by a delegate
        services.Configure<PublishingAppSettings>(myOptions => { myOptions = configFromDb(dbConnectionFactory); });
    }
```

But, I know that I have something wrong in that Lambda function because I get back NULL objects when I use the options.

What did I do wrong?